# How to report receive queue size for AF_UNIX sockets

Tags: networking, socket, netstat, unix-sockets

`netstat -a` reports `Recv-Q` (amount of unread data pending for a reading application) for `AF_INET` sockets, but not `AF_UNIX` sockets (at least not for `SOCK_DGRAM`).

Does anybody know a way to obtain this information for `AF_UNIX` sockets from outside of the process itself?

Barring reporting the *amount*, is there a way to tell if there is **any** unread data pending for the application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out a way. On Linux the `ss` program is kind of like `netstat` on steroids - it provides much more information, including the amount of data pending in receive buffers for `AF_UNIX` sockets. I like

> ss -ax

for my purposes. Man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html

See also my answer here:
[How to see the amount of pending data on a unix domain socket?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114400/how-to-see-the-amount-of-pending-data-on-a-unix-domain-socket/182710#182710)

Also: [Intro to SS (some details not found on man page - particularly filters)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html)